# shift+click couldn't select correct items with listview

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

in my ListView, I want to press ctrl+A to select all items, and select multiple items cooperate with shift button. But it doesn't work. I use keybinding to rewrite select all command, but how to deal with select multiple items with shift button?

XAML:

```
 <ListView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
              SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestContent}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SelectAllCommand}"
                        Modifiers="Control"
                        Key="A"/>
        </ListView.InputBindings>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ICommand SelectAllCommand { protected set; get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSelectAllCommand);

        TestList = new List<Test>();
        InitializeList();
    }

    private void ExecuteSelectAllCommand()
    {
        foreach (var v in this.TestList)
        {
            v.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            this.TestList.Add(new Test() { TestContent = i.ToString(), IsSelected = false });
        }
    }

    public List<Test> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class Test : NotificationObject
{
    public string TestContent { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }

        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Since my real ListView will load items from server, it may contains a large number of items, so I have to use VirtualizationPanel.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Just drop your ExecuteSelectAllCommand and the InputBindings. Then it will work as expected, because what you are trying to rebuild is already the default behavior.

Comment: If I remove those code, ctrl+A couldn't select all items, I think it is caused by I set VirtualizationPanel.IsVirtualization as true.

Comment: It works for me if I don't set `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`. However, I am not sure if it is generally a good idea to try to select a very large number of items at once, when you also want to bind a view model item property to the selection state of the ListViewItem.

Comment: If I don't set VirtualizationMode as Recycling, a large number of items will lead performance poor. Selecting a large number of items is business logic, so I couldn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a behavior if you're going to bind `SelectedItems` to a visualizing panel for obvious reasons: if the item doesn't need to be loaded, then it doesn't exist.

I ran into this problem and used an approach Telerik required users to use with their `RadGridView`.

You can find that approach [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/vladimirenchev/posts/10-05-31/how-to-synchronize-your-ui-selected-items-with-your-data-context-using-mvvm-and-blend-behaviors-for-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx)